# Как вызвать по таймеру метод из другого метода объекта в javaScript?

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой код (почти все лишнее выкинуто): создается объект класса Оbj и запускается метод инициализации. Сейчас понадобилось добавить setInterval() в этот метод инициализации, чтобы один из методов выполнялся регулярно по таймеру.

Вопрос: подскажите как вызвать метод process() в setInterval(), который лежит методе init() этого же объекта? И возможно ли это вообще?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Obj(id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.init = function() {
            setInterval('this.process()', 1000);
        }
        this.process = function() {
            // do something
        }
    }

    var Obj1 = new Obj('some_id');
    Obj1.init();

</script>
```

Я понимаю, что могу вызвать его setInterval('Obj1.process()', 1000); после создания класса. Но, хочется задать этот таймер именно внутри объекта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, вот так

```
function Obj(id) {
    var self = this;
    this.id = id;
    this.init = function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            self.process();
        }, 1000);
    };
    this.process = function() {
        // do something
    };
}
```

Comment: Так вы self не объявили. И стоит точку с запятой ставить между, как я скекунду назад добавил

Comment: не работает uncaught exception
[не тот код скопировал в прошлый раз], вот правильный:

<code><html>
<head>
 <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

 function Obj(id) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = id;
  this.init = function() {
   this.process();
   setInterval(function() {
    self.process();
   }, 5000);
  }
     this.process = function() {
      alert(this.id);
     }
 }

 var Obj1 = new Obj('some_id');
 Obj1.init();

</script>

</body>
</html></code>

Comment: немного парит uncaught exception, но в целом вроде все ок. Спасибо! :)

Comment: У меня какие-то ошибки тоже идут.. но там исходник указан: http://hashcode.ru/m/default/media/js/wmd/wmd.js

Comment: точно! это косяк в хэшкоде какой-то :) (thumbs up!)

Answer (score 0):

Установите интервал таким образом:

```
setInterval(this.process, 1000);
```

Comment: Но тогда при вызове process не будет иметь this-указатель, если не ошибаюсь.. а если так, то id будте утрачен

Comment: так не будет работать

Comment: да, вы правы

Answer (score 0):

Теперь с помощью классов эту задачу можно решить так:

```js
class Obj {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  init() {
    setInterval(this.process, 1000);
  }

  process() {
    console.log('do something');
  }
}

const obj = new Obj(5);

obj.init();
```